# How to put a char from a .Dat file to a char string holder programming c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 255
#define T 100

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX];
    int score;
} Student;

int main()
{
    Student stud, temp[T];
    char hnm[T][MAX];
    int x,i,hsc,h;
    FILE *fptr;

    if ((fptr=fopen("scores.dat","a+"))==NULL) {
        printf("File Opening was unsuccessful");
    }
    else {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        getchar();
        for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
            scanf("%s %d",&stud.name, &stud.score);
            fprintf(fptr,"%s %d\n", stud.name, stud.score);
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    if ((fptr=fopen("scores.dat","r"))==NULL) {
        printf("File Opening was unsuccessful");
    }
    else {
        i = 0;
        temp[i].name = stud.name;
        temp[i].score = stud.score;
        fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", &stud.name, &stud.score);
        while(!feof(fptr)) {
            temp[i].name = stud.name;
            temp[i].score = stud.score;
            fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", &stud.name, &stud.score);
            i++;
        }
        system("pause");
        x=sizeof(fptr);
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    for(i=0;i<x-1;i++) {
        for(h=0;h<x-i-1;h++) {
            if(temp[h].score<temp[h+1].score) {
                hsc=temp[h].score;
                temp[h].score=temp[h+1].score;
                temp[h+1].score=hsc;

                hnm[h]=temp[h].name;
                temp[h].name=temp[h+1].name;
                temp[h+1].name = hnm[h];
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%s %d\n",temp[i].name1, temp[i].score);
    }

    if((fptr=fopen("scores.dat","w"))==NULL) {
        printf("File Opening was unsuccessful");
    }
    else {
        for(i=0;i<20;i++){
            fprintf(fptr,"%s %d\n", temp[i].name, temp[i].score);
            printf("Top #%d: %s %d\n",i+1, temp[i].name, temp[i].score);
        }

    }
    fclose(fptr);


    return 0;
}
```

The code is simple the program will ask for the user to input number of test cases and ask for name and score.

Sample input:

```
 4
 Name1 100
 Name2 900
 Name3 800
 Name4 150
```

Then puts it in a .Dat file.
Then sort it from highest to lowest.
Then outputs the top 20 (hence only 20 if some of the score that is in the dat, it will be disregarded.)

My only problem in the code is how do I get it from the File. I know how to sort.  But how do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to consume newline char after `fcanf`
2. You need to use `strcpy` to copy student name.

Use this:

```
        i = 0;            
        fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", &stud.name, &stud.score);
        fgetc(fptr);
        while(!feof(fptr)) {
             strcpy(temp[i].name,stud.name);
            temp[i].score = stud.score;
            fscanf(fptr,"%s %d", &stud.name, &stud.score);
            fgetc(fptr);
            i++;
        }
        system("pause");
        x=sizeof(fptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf with string formater can be a bit tricky to get right, I would suggest you do something like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
{
  char buffer[255];
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fptr) != NULL)
  {
    char *p = strchr(buffer, ' '); // find ' '
    if (p!=NULL)
    {
      *p++ = '\0'; // terminate first string
      strncpy(temp[i].name, buffer, MAX); // copy string
      temp[i].name[MAX-1] = '\0'; // in case name is too long, truncate
      temp[i].score = atoi(p); // get score, whitespace will be ignored
    }
  }
}
```